# Why my NextJS website on Vercel doesn’t work properly on mobile?

Tags: image, next.js, vercel

I just deployed my NextJS website to vercel and for some reason its looks really bad on mobile
The picture aren’t being rendered properly and the video bg doesn’t appear

I think it might be related to the fact that im not using Next/image
but that’s because I haven’t find a solution to implement a fixed background attachment without using the background image property.

Would love for you help

Here is a link to the website:
https://luciana-website.vercel.app/

i mostly inspected the website and tried to figure out what is not working but I didn’t manage to find the exact problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. For video : add the `playsinline` tag - assuming webkit browsers like iPhone is where you are having issues - see here [https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/#:~:text=On%20iPhone%2C%20%3Cvideo%20playsinline%3E%20elements%20will%20now%20be%20allowed%20to%20play%20inline%2C%20and%20will%20not%20automatically%20enter%20fullscreen%20mode%20when%20playback%20begins](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/#:%7E:text=On%20iPhone%2C%20%3Cvideo%20playsinline%3E%20elements%20will%20now%20be%20allowed%20to%20play%20inline%2C%20and%20will%20not%20automatically%20enter%20fullscreen%20mode%20when%20playback%20begins).
2. For your images, they are 1200px and you are adding a `bg-cover` so its not resizing and only showing coreners.

#### Further notes

- You are sending a 19.2mb video, consider running it through a streaming service

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! 
Do you have an recommendation for a streaming service? 
Does YouTube works?  And what should I do instead of bg-cover?

Comment: 1. For  streaming service, you could try something like cloudinary or vimeo which allow playing video's inline. 

2. it looks like `bg-cover` is supposed to do what you want but there is a conflict based on what you chained here 

`relative h-screen w-screen bg-dinning bg-cover bg-fixed flex justify-start items-end text-center text-white p-20` - try retaining `bg-cover` while you remove other classes to find the culprit. 

If this or another answer helped you, Please accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. As for the playinline it didn’t work. Also the bug doesn’t appear when I’m using the dev tool to view the website on mobile … only after i deploying it I can see the changes. Do you have a way where I can see the changes without deploying the website every time?

Comment: Here is a codesandbox with your autoplay working (checked on my phone) -  https://2ypf1f.csb.app/  and the code reference

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-galileo-2ypf1f?file=/index.html

Comment: you could add your source code on github and then change the link to `githubbox` which will get you a code sandbox that you can play around with which will reflect immediately - see my example above - bonus, you can then deploy a pipeline via vercel to your site - Read more about it here https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/vercel-for-github

Comment: For some reason when im using the video tag and the source tag the video doesn't work... Only when I'm using <video src=...>

Comment: anyway i tried different solutions (including adding the playinline) and none of them is working. I removed all the CSS classed and still the images are being rendered in a weird way. any chance that related to vercel?

Comment: Can you put in your code in stack blitz or code sandbox ?